# $H^1$ of a constant sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be an irreducible smooth curve, and $\underline{k(X)}$ the constant sheaf on $X$ with  the function field $k(X)$ as fibers.

Reading from Serre's *Algebraic groups and class fields* I met the claim ($H$ denotes sheaf cohomology)
$$ H^1(X, \underline{k(X)}) = 0 $$
motivated by the sentence: "the nerve of every open cover of $X$ is a simplex".

I don't know what the nerve of an open cover is, but anyway the above claim seems quite intuitive: an element of $H^1$ is a section of $\underline{k(X)}$ defined only on the intersection of pairs of opens of a cover of $X$. Such a local section, in our case, **always** comes from the restriction of a globally defined section. After all the sheaf is constant, and a global section consists of a collection of an arbitrary regular function for every point of $X$, with any kind of *jumps* allowed.

Is my reasoning correct? Could you please help me to formalize it?

Comment: The nerve certainly need not be a simplex, are you sure Serre said that?

Comment: The argument you offer doesn't really use properties of either $H^1$ or $k(X)$. Are you sure you haven't just proved that $H^1(X, A)$ vanishes for any constant sheaf $A$ whatsoever (an absurdity to be sure)?

Comment: @Marek: no absurdity at all, but you have to suppose that $X$ is irreducible.

Comment: @Georges: indeed, thank you. But OP didn't mention irreducibility in their reasoning at all, therefore my comment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Result**
If $X$ is an irreducible topological space and $\underline A$ the constant sheaf associated to the abelian group $A$, then we have for the first  Čech cohomology group   $\check H^1(X,\underline A)=0$ .
**Proof**
It suffices to prove that, for an arbitrary covering $\mathcal U =(U_i)_{i\in I}$ we have $ \check H^1(\mathcal U,\underline A)=0$.
Given a cocycle $(g_{ij})\in  Z^1(\mathcal U,\underline A)$, fix some $i_0\in I$ and define the $0$-cochain $(h_i)\in  C^0(\mathcal U,\underline A)$ by $h_i=g_{i_0i}$.  The cocycle condition $g_{i_0j}=g_{i_0i}+g_{ij}$ translates into $h_j=h_i+g_{ij}$ or $g_{ij}=h_j-h_i$.
This proves that the cocycle $(g_{ij})$ is the coboundary of the cochain $(h_i)$, and thus  that the class of that  cocycle is zero in $ \check H^1(\mathcal U,\underline A)$.
Since $(g_{ij})$ was an arbitrary cocycle, we have  $ \check H^1(\mathcal U,\underline A)=0$, as promised.

**Check your understanding**
Where on earth did I use that our  sheaf is constant and that $X$ is irreducible ?!
**Edit: Answer**
When I defined $h_i=g_{i_0i}$.
Since $g_{i_0i}\in \Gamma(U_{i_0i},\underline A)$ and $h_i\in \Gamma(U_i,\underline A)$,  the definition   $h_i=g_{i_0i}$ only makes sense because $\Gamma(U_i,\underline A)=\Gamma(U_{i_0i},\underline A)=A$.
See Remark 1) below where I emphasize that $\Gamma(U,\underline A)=A$ for all open non-empty $U$'s.

**Remarks**
1) The irreducibility of $X$ implies that the constant **presheaf** associated to $A$ is already a sheaf i.e. that the constant sheaf $\underline A$ is given by $\Gamma(U,\underline A)=A$ for all open non-empty subsets $U\subset X$.
(For reducible topological spaces $\Gamma(U,\underline A)$ consists of **locally constant**  maps  $U \to A$)
This implies that $\underline A$ is flabby (=flasque).
2) For arbitrary flabby sheaves $\mathcal F$  on arbitrary topological spaces $Y$ both Čech cohomology groups and genuine cohomology  groups (as introduced by Grothedieck through derived functors)  are zero in all positive degrees : $\check {H}^n(Y,\mathcal F)=H^n(Y,\mathcal F)=0$ for $n\gt 0$.
3) And to finish  on a pleasant note:  Čech cohomology groups and genuine cohomology  groups always coincide in degree $1$ for all sheaves $\mathcal G$ of abelian groups, flabby or not:  $\check {H}^1(Y,\mathcal G)=H^1(Y,\mathcal G)$.

Comment: I'll soon answer my question posed in "Check your understanding" but meanwhile I encourage everybody to comment on it.

Comment: Here's where you used that $\underline{A}$ is constant: if we consider an arbitrary sheaf $\mathscr{F}$, then we are not sure that the so defined $h_i$ belongs to $\mathscr{F}(U_i)$. This is because $h_i\in \mathscr{F}(U_i\cap U_{i_0})$, which contains but it's not necessarily equal to $ \mathscr{F}(U_i)$. Anyway, thanks for the great answer Georges!

Comment: +1: Bravo Abramo, spot on! (Abramo wrote his comment **before** I answered my own question in an edit).

Comment: I'll just add that the nerve of any covering is indeed a simplex for irreducible spaces since intersection of non-empty opens is again non-empty (a fact that is neatly hidden in your nice answer).

Comment: Thank you for that interesting comment, dear @Marek.